# SQL MERGE from two tables as source

Tags: sql-server, merge, sql-update, sql-insert

I've three tables and want to `MERGE` into table `customer`. But as source I need two tables: `adress` and `ascust`. `adress` and `ascust` are linked by column `custnr` like this:

```
SELECT adress.custnr, ascust.masternr
FROM adress INNER JOIN ascust 
ON adress.custnr = ascust.custnr
```

This is my current `MERGE` statement:

```
MERGE INTO dbo.customer d USING dbo.adress s1 on d.number = s1.custnr and d.lfdnr = s1.lfdnr
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET d.name = s1.name, d.masternr = s2.masternr
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (name, masternr) VALUES (s1.name, s2.masternr);
```

As you can see, I need to `UPDATE` and `INSERT` column `masternr` from `s2` (table `ascust`). How can I include `s2` (table `ascust`) in my `MERGE` statement?

Comment: Just put the top query into a CTE and use that as the source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to do like this:

```
MERGE INTO dbo.customer d USING 
                (SELECT adress.custnr, adress.lfdnr, ascust.masternr
                 FROM adress INNER JOIN ascust 
                            ON adress.custnr = ascust.custnr
                ) s1 on d.number = s1.custnr and d.lfdnr = s1.lfdnr

WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET d.name = s1.name, d.masternr = s1.masternr
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (name, masternr) VALUES (s1.name, s1.masternr);
```

Comment: Thanks for providing the solution. Currently I'm using a CTE.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to `Dave Brown` for the hint with `CTE`. It works great.

```
WITH cte1 AS
(       
    SELECT adress.custnr, ascust.masternr, adress.lfdnr
    FROM adress INNER JOIN ascust 
    ON adress.custnr = ascust.custnr
)
MERGE INTO dbo.customer d USING cte1 s on d.number = s.custnr and d.lfdnr = s.lfdnr
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET d.name = s.name, d.masternr = s.masternr
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (name, masternr) VALUES (s.name, s.masternr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query should be like this :

```
MERGE INTO dbo.customer d USING (SELECT adress.custnr, ascust.masternr
FROM adress INNER JOIN ascust 
ON adress.custnr = ascust.custnr) s1 on d.number = s1.custnr and d.lfdnr = s1.lfdnr
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET d.name = s1.name, d.masternr = s2.masternr
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (name, masternr) VALUES (s1.name, s2.masternr);
```